# Threads using the same resource

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, uart

I have C# multi threading program that using UART trough c++ COM object. I'm accessing UART from couple threads and it is not aloud.
Mu solutions:

1. access to UART only from one thread and perform all other threads requests in the beginning of each cycle. The problem with this solution is that all other threads will wait a lot of time before receiving response.
2. Create prioritized thread that only he will access UART. The problem with this solution is that it is very risky.
   What solution is the best and why? There is another solution?

Comment: Why do you consider option 2 "risky"? Any particular reason (as it seem much safer/easier to understand than option 1 where the thread seem to be doing some other unrelated work too)?

Comment: It is risky because there is need to change all existing product and it can cause bugs after users will upgrade.

Comment: Are you sure that 1 is actually a problem? Have you actually measured if there is indeed "lot of time before receiving response" and that time is not attributed to slowness of device/UART?

Comment: Yes I'm sure because each cycle in thread 1 can take second and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a dedicated thread that pulls requests from a `ConcurrentQueue` and operates on the UART.
All other threads should `Enqueue` requests and continue on with their work, so there's no waiting involved. Does that fit your needs?

Here's the documentation for [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: +1. dedicated thread (option 2) seem very straight forward (and expected) solution in this case.

Comment: Can I use it as prioritized queue? That means that all request that will come from thread 1 will be executed before requests from thread 2?

Comment: It's clearer to use 2 queues in this case. One for high priority and the second for others. just make sure to first dequeue from the high priority one.